# # Json (newsoft) - getting specific elements

Tags: c#, json, linq, nested

I have the following JSon string

```
   {
                 'id': '346582587961401930',
                 'form_id': '62455437457962',
                 'ip': '79.123.81.69',
                 'created_at': '2016-08-09 16:09:47',
                 'status': 'ACTIVE',
                 'new': '0',
                 'flag': '0',
                 'updated_at': '2016-08-09 16:10:49',
                 'answers': {
                    '4': {
                      'text': '<p><span style=\'font-size:14pt;\'><strong>Ethical Leaders. Global Changemakers</strong></span></p>',
                      'type': 'control_text'
                    },
                    '5': {
                      'text': ' ',
                      'type': 'control_textbox',
                      'answer': 'John'
                    },
                    '6': {
                      'type': 'control_textbox',
                      'text': 'Middle'
                    },
                    '7': {
                      'text': ' ',
                      'type': 'control_textbox',
                      'answer': 'Smith'
                    },
                    '8': {
                      'text': 'Address',
                      'type': 'control_address'
                    },
                    '9': {
                      'text': 'E-mail',
                      'type': 'control_email',
                      'answer': 'JSmith@gmail.com'
                    },
                    '10': {
                      'text': 'Cell phone',
                      'type': 'control_phone',
                      'answer': {
                         'area': '213',
                         'phone': '3923095'
                      },
                      'prettyFormat': '(213) 3923095'
                    },
                    '11': {
                      'type': 'control_textbox',
                      'text': 'Anticipated Start Semester / Year',
                      'answer': '2018 Fall'
                    },
                    '13': {
                      'type': 'control_textbox',
                      'text': 'Current high school / College',
                      'answer': 'Wood Ranch'
                    },
                    '14': {
                      'type': 'control_textbox',
                      'text': 'Event name',
                      'answer': 'Testing'
                    },
                    '15': {
                      'type': 'control_textarea',
                      'text': 'Notes',
                      'answer': 'This is a test'
                    },
                    '16': {
                      'text': 'Home phone',
                      'type': 'control_phone'
                    },
                    '12': {
                      'answer': 'Biology and Bioethics (Pre-Med)\r\nUnknown'
                    }
                 }
              }
```

The element with 'number' represent question id like '4'.

In C# (using Newtonsoft.Json; using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;) I am looking for a way to search and extract specific questions based on the id and for each get properties values. If the properties are also a JSon I would like to be able to get them as well.

For example:

I would like to get the value of 'answer' property of question id '5' and the 'area' and 'phone' under 'answer' in question id '10'
I tried different approaches but could not find a consistent way to get it

Thanks

myalo

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Different things. I tried using JArray parsing but the string that I am getting does not have [ ]. I can get everything by using reader like JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(sub)); but then I have to check each element. Some of the strings can have 100 + answers and I need to get to just a few so I am looking for search to get specific ones. Similarly I tried to cast it to dynamic data = JObject.Parse(sub); and then do for each as I could not get to '5' for example. Maybe because it is a number?

Comment: why not just deserialize the object?

Comment: Which I did like this JObject answers = JObject.Parse(answersData); doing foreach on answers I can get to what I need but I am trying not to iterate through all. I can get tens of submissions with 100 + answers so I am looking for way to get to a specific question and specific property. Thanks

Comment: there is nearly no noticeable difference between iterating over 10 or 100 elements. What you are looking for is partial parsing json which I don't think any of the json library supports.

Comment: I understand that the difference can be minimal in today's computing. I would like to add - the JSon is based on form submissions (jotForm). Our staff can create many different ones. Most will have common fields. Each form will have data mapping - question x relates to database column y. IMHO It is cleaner to iterate over the mapped fields and for each question get the answer in a particular submission as opposed to iterate through all the answers and for each iterate through the needed questions and if the answer is of needed question get the properties. Thank you.

Comment: as I mentioned, what you are looking for is to partially parse json. You will most likely have to implement the deserializer yourself in this case

Comment: I agree but I was looking for a cleaner code. See my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have so far and it works for me by using dynamic twice. The code looks cleaner without the iteration

```
            dynamic data = JObject.Parse(sub);
            Console.WriteLine("id:" + data.id.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("ip:" + data.ip.ToString());
            string answersData = data.answers.ToString();
            //JObject answers = JObject.Parse(answersData);
            dynamic danswers = JObject.Parse(answersData);
            //get each answer - here we will use the mapping
          //to-do: replace Console with saving to data store

            Console.WriteLine("First name= " + (string)danswers["5"]["answer"]);
            Console.WriteLine("Middle Name= " + getAnswer(danswers, "6", "control_textbox"));

            Console.WriteLine("Last Name=" + getAnswer(danswers,"7","control_textbox"));
            Console.WriteLine("Address=" + getAnswer(danswers, "8", "control_textbox"));
            Console.WriteLine("Email=" + getAnswer(danswers, "9", "control_textbox"));
            Console.WriteLine("Phone=" + getAnswer(danswers, "10", "control_textbox"));
            Console.WriteLine("Anticipated Start Semester=" + getAnswer(danswers, "11", "control_textbox"));
            Console.WriteLine("Current high school / College=" + getAnswer(danswers, "13", "control_textbox"));
            Console.WriteLine("Event name=" + getAnswer(danswers, "14", "control_textbox"));
            Console.WriteLine("Notes=" + getAnswer(danswers, "15", "control_textbox"));
          Console.ReadLine();
```

And getAnswer is

```
  private static string getAnswer(JObject danswers,string qid, string answertype)
  { 
        // more "type" later
      string returnValue = "";
      if (danswers[qid] != null && ((string)danswers[qid]["type"] == "control_textbox" || (string)danswers[qid]["type"] == "control_email" || (string)danswers[qid]["type"] == "control_textarea"))
      {
          returnValue = (string)danswers[qid]["answer"];
      }
      else
      {
         //need better error
          returnValue = "Not found or type is not handled";
      }
      return (returnValue);
  }
```